# Large Scale VHDL modularization techniques

Tags: cpu, naming, code-organization, vhdl

I'm thinking about implimenting a 16 bit CPU in VHDL.
A simplish CPU.
ADD, MULS, NEG, BitShift, JUMP, Relitive Jump, BREQ, Relitive BREQ, i don't know somethign along these lines>
Probably all only working with 16bit operands.
I might even cut it down and use only a single operand and a accumulator.
With Some status regitsters, Carry, Zero, Neg (unless i use a Accumlator),

I know how to design all the parts from logic gates, and plan to build them up from first priciples,
So for my ALU I'll need to 'build' a ADDer, proably a Carry Look ahead, group adder,
this adder it self is make up oa a couple of parts, wich are themselves made up of a couple of parts.

Anyway, my problem is not the CPU design, or the VHDL (i know the language, more or less).
It's how i should keep things organised.
How should I use packages,
How should I name my processes and port maps? (i've never seen the benifit of naming the port maps, or processes)

Comment: I found this http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=vhdl+source+project+structure to be a fruitful query. Having had a passing familiarity with VHDL, two recommendations from that search result were very software-ish: use a VHDL aware editor, and most importantly, use revision control (git and mercurial are favorites for individual projects). Unfortunately, many programmers don't consider VHDL programming, so I wouldn't expect much here at SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at some existing [examples](http://opencores.org/projects?cat=10&lang=1&stage=0&lic=0) wouldn't hurt. At the level you're talking about (naming conventions and such) I've never really done much different in hardware design than in software.

As an aside, I'd generally advise *against* doing things like your own adders and such, unless it's something that's required because it's homework, or something like that. With FPGA's and (to a *slightly* lesser extent) ASICs, you have an existing "library" of hardware in the device, so some thing like `A <= B + c` will typically use an adder circuit that's already built into the device in the case of an FPGA or a hand-optimized hard macro in the case of an ASIC.

Writing your own will take a fair amount of extra work, and it'll almost always produce a worse result. In the case of an ASIC, it'll be a little worse; in the case of an FPGA, it'll usually be quite a bit worse.

Edit: I should also note that a simple CPU doesn't really qualify as a large-scale design, at least IMO. Maybe it's due to my background in software, but I've always found CPU design fairly straightforward. Just for one example, the one time I did a DRAM controller, it seemed like a *lot* more work to me. I don't recall anything like source code line counts, but based on memory, I'd say it was larger (probably by something like 2x). Of course, it'll depend on exactly how simple of a CPU you decide on too...

Comment: By Large Scale design, I'm asking about, not nesc beacuse this is a example of large scale design, but because the techniques used in large scale design are relivent.

Comment: As to Creating my own adders: This isn't home work, but it is what i need to study.
Designing/understanding Adders and multipliers is part of a unit i'm doing (wich also covers VHDL, but not nesc both together). CPU design is part of a unit i'm doing (but has already been tested, and won't be tested again) this unit doesn;'t cover VHDL at all though

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do, be sure to read Jiri Gaisler's master work on structured VHDL design method.

http://www.gaisler.com/doc/vhdl2proc.pdf
http://www.gaisler.com/doc/structdes.pdf

You'll be very glad you did.